# javascript + combine json arrays based on key,

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, underscore.js

I am trying to merger two json to one json. I don't want merge all keys, I added my code. 
Code should be in javascript or node (underscore).

```
var json1 = [{user_id:1,friend_id:2,desc:'aaa'}, {user_id:3,friend_id:4,desc:'ccc'}, {user_id:1,friend_id:1,desc:'ccc'} , {user_id:1,friend_id:3,desc:'ccc'} ];


var json2 = [{reference_id:1,name:'A'},{reference_id:2,name:'B'},{reference_id:3,name:'C',age:30},{reference_id:4,name:'D'}];
```

Expecting Output:

output:

```
json1 = [{user_id:1,friend_id:2,desc:'aaa',user_name:'A',friend_name:'B'}, {user_id:3,friend_id:4,desc:'ccc',user_name:'C',friend_name:'D'}, {user_id:1,friend_id:1,desc:'ccc',user_name:'A',friend_name:'A'} , {user_id:1,friend_id:3,desc:'ccc',user_name:'A',friend_name:'C'} ];
```

Logic Js Code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json1.length; i++) {
    var user_id = json1[i].user_id;
    var friend_id = json1[i].friend_id;
    for (var j = 0; j < json2.length; j++) {
        if (json2[j].reference_id == user_id) {
             json1[i].user_name = json2[j].name;
        }
        if (json2[j].reference_id == friend_id) {
             json1[i].friend_name = json2[j].name;
        }
    }
}
```

I attached my code in jsfiddle.[Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rajinikumarr/3wtuwmtf/)

The same code should be convert into underscore.

Comment: I'd first reconfigure the second array to be an object with keys from *referenceId* and values *name*, then it's just an iteration over the first array to augment the data. Note that "JSON" is a notation that borrows from ECMAScript object literal notation. What you have are array and object literals, not "JSON".

Comment: @RobG - why you deleted your coded. pls post it. i will check

Comment: You should be able to see deleted posts, it's essentially the same as Chas Brown's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are repeating some effort here. Doesn't really matter if json2.length is small; but if it is large you will pay a penalty: you are looping over every element of json2 for every time you look at an element of json1. So instead, think of it this way:

```
var personMap = {};
json2.forEach(function(item) {
    personMap[item.reference_id] = item.name;
});

json1.forEach(function(item) {
    item.user_name = personMap[item.user_id];
    item.friend_name = personMap[item.friend_id];
});
```

Comment: @RobG: The endless race :)

Comment: The only differences are I used *reduce* rather than *forEach* and test whether the name exists first, but likely that's not required. Up to the OP anyway.

Comment: In my case some time the name key also not available in json2.

Comment: *reduce* is nicer and idiomatic; but I figured it would be a bit confusing, given user's likely context.

Comment: @RSKMR: If it is not available, what do you expect to happen? In this approach you will get "user_name: undefined"; what else did you want?

Comment: Nice tips. Thanks for both @ChasBrown and RobG

Comment: @RSKMR: If it answered your question, consider marking it as 'accepted'. That helps other users (plus I get some chocolate!)

Answer (score 1):

Your code in plain vanilla JS should work, except for "==" in the places where you've mistakenly put "=".

Replace these:

```
if (json2[j].reference_id = user_id) {
...
if (json2[j].reference_id = friend_id) {
...
```

with these:

```
if (json2[j].reference_id == user_id) {
...
if (json2[j].reference_id == friend_id) {
```

Try this is underscore:

```
_.map(json1, function(item){ 
    var user_id = item.user_id;
    var friend_id = item.friend_id;

    _.map(json2, function(item2){

    if (item2.reference_id == user_id) {
         item.user_name = item2.name;
       }
    if (item2.reference_id == friend_id) {
         item.friend_name = item2.name;
    }
});


 });
```

Comment: Oh god. Yes I missed the == . Thanks. It's my fault only.

Comment: Its possible using underscore. I will add the vote for you because I done my mistake, you found that.

Comment: @RSKMR - check the underscore code above, it should work